# Did the new Kirk ever mind meld with Spock Prime?

Tags: star-trek

I can't remember, but I thought they had in the film. If so-wouldn't he then learn everything from Spock regarding the former timeline?

Comment: Are you thinking possibly of Captain Pike?

Comment: new kirk mind melds with old spock, but old spock is able to control the flows and only showed kirk what he needed to know about nero.

Comment: @Himarm That looks suspiciously like an answer:  Grab yourself a couple of references (screencaps of the meld?) and post it down below!

Answer (score 2):

Kirk and old Spock do Mind Meld in the Star Trek 2009 movie.

Here is a link to the scene. In the scene old Spock shows Kirk how he ended up time traveling with Nero to the past.

In the movie its pretty clear the sharing went 1 way, Old Spock to Kirk, and that Old Spock also limits what he shares to Kirk to what we the viewer sees.

Comment: Would it being "one way" be partly down to Spock being vulcan (well half vulcan) and Kirk being a human (possible both persons have to be telepathic for it to be two way)?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix na, vulcans (even half vulcans) can both share their mind, as well as see into the targets minds. 

young spock does this in a slightly later scene, using a mind meld on one of Nero's crew to find out the information he needs, and again young spock uses a mind meld on admiral pike to see what hes feeling in "star trek into darkness"

Comment: Can the person who Spock is melding with actually see into Spock's mind if they aren't telepathic?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix yes, thats literally whats happening in this scene, spock lets kirk look into his mind and see these specific memories bringing them to this point in the movie.